# Why is DWITHIN filtering my data with native EPSG 4326 with meters instead of degrees?

Tags: geoserver, epsg, cql-filter, units

Ok so I have a PostgreSQL Table, to which I added a PostGIS geometry column using:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public','my_table','geom',4326,'POINT',2);
```

Followed by:

```
UPDATE public.my_table
SET geom = st_geometryfromtext('POINT('|| lon ||' '|| lat ||')',4326);
```

I then publish this table as WFS 1.0.0 using Geoserver 2.12.0. When I make a query using filter

```
DWITHIN(geom, Point(lon lat), distanceInDegrees, meters)
```

my query returns geojson with zero features.

If I query using

```
DWITHIN(geom, Point(lon lat), distanceInMeters, meters)
```

then I get correct results within the specified radius. I simply cannot figure out why the units are meters and not degrees when native EPSG is 4326? In the past when I have published layers as 4326, DWITHIN always took only degree units.

The layer configs in Geoserver:

native srs - EPSG:4326

declared srs - EPSG:4326

srs handing - Force Declared

Comment: Can you repeat the issue if you save the states shapefile from the GeoServer demo data into PostGIS and publish it?

Comment: Isn't that to be expected? What happens if you specify the unit as degrees?

Comment: @Ian Turton Degrees are expected, the parameter specifying the unit doesn't matter see reply to [this post] (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132251/dwithin-wfs-filter-is-not-working). Geoserver expects a valid value but uses the native SRS to execute the DWITHIN regardless of what units you enter.

Comment: I think it used to do that but it is now fixed for postgis stores

Comment: Apparently it still is not fixed, when I run 
    DWITHIN(geom,Point(-77.051333 38.802610), 1,statute miles)
I get zero features returned. But I get 17 features when I run
    DWITHIN(geom,Point(-77.051333 38.802610), 1609.34,meters).

Unit as 'degrees' is not permited as I got the following response from Geoserver:
    Could not parse CQL filter list.
Encountered "degrees" at line 1, column 45.
Was expecting one of:
    "feet" ...
    "meters" ...
    "statute miles" ...
    "nautical miles" ...
    "kilometers" ...

Comment: @User30184 So I did some testing and this is the results that I found. If I start with `table_1` and add a geom column. The units are meters, even though I specify 4326 in `AddGeometryColumn()`. If I open `table_1` in QGIS and then save it as `table_1.shp` with 4326 and reimport into my DB then republish, the units are now in degrees such that `DWITHIN(geom,Point(-77.051333 38.802610), 1,statute miles)` returns almost every feature and `DWITHIN(geom,Point(-77.051333 38.802610), 0.01628546
,statute miles)` returns the correct number of features within 1 mile.

Comment: Please clarify. How did you create "table_1"?

Comment: I did 

`CREATE TABLE public.table_1 (GID bigserial PRIMARY KEY ... some other fields);` 

followed by 

`SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public','table_1','geom',4326,'POINT',2);` and then 

`UPDATE public.table_1 SET geom = st_geometryfromtext('POINT('|| lon ||' '|| lat ||')',4326);`

Comment: To clarify, `AddGeometryColumn` and update on the geom field was done after inserting the rows via insert statements.