# GeoServer WFS buffer function

Tags: geoserver, wfs, query

I am trying to check intersection with buffered area of shape:

--This works

```
&cql_filter=INTERSECTS(shape, POLYGON((-90 40, -90 45, -60 45, -60 40, -90 40)))
```

--This does not

```
&cql_filter=INTERSECTS(buffer(shape,1), POLYGON((-90 40, -90 45, -60 45, -60 40, -90 40)))
```

Although it´s not quite clear what is returned by the buffer, is this geometry?

> buffer    geometry:Geometry,  distance:Double Returns the buffered area around the geometry using the specified distance

Is there any other way to do this via WFS?

Comment: Try DWITHIN https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132251/dwithin-wfs-filter-is-not-working.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.